# Is it possible to use any program as a library?

Tags: debugging, compiler-construction, elf, disassembly

I'm trying to create some debug scripts with compiled programs, for this I'm trying to create something where I prepare my variables in some code I generate and then jump into another program.

Is there a way to do that ? For example by having some C code and then jumping to a label or place in the executable. For now I'm focusing on ELF programs, but if something exists on Windows I'm also interested !

Thanks !

I've tried to bring back the ELF file into a .s for GCC and recompile, however this doesn't seem to work well for all ELF files (e.g non-PIE binaries). And I've looked to see if there were tools that would create a .s but they are either buggy, incomplete or both.

Comment: If you just need to run an initializer function before `main` is entered, can't you use an ELF constructor function?

Comment: I would want to run an initializer before calling a function.

Comment: This sounds like an http://xyproblem.info. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to take an existing binary, and create programs that will parse inputs and jump to a function of this existing binary. This would be useful to do debugging/testing in CTF.